# How can I print one to many relationship result in php?

Tags: php

I am getting below table as result for my query.

```
id     name   celebrity
------------------------
1      A       X
1      A       Y
1      A       Z
2      B       M
2      B       N
```

I want to print this table result as below using php.

```
1->A->X,Y,z

2->B->M,N
```

I am getting above table as associative array after querying with mysql database. Can anyone help me to write a logic to print the table result as above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by mysql

```
select id, name, group_concat(celebrity)  
   from te table
 group by id, name
```